# Problema con Model.create()

Tags: nodejs, reactjs, backend, frontend, model

Hola tengo un problema con el User.create ya que me dice que no es una funcion cuando intento registrar un usuario en la pagina. Estoy haciendo el backend con Node.js y Express y el frontend esta echo con una Api en React.js, la base de datos que estoy usando es MYSQL. Queria saber si alguno me puede ayudar de porque puede ser el error. Si es un problema de semantica de tipeo o simplemente estoy codiando mal. Dejo el modelo de user, la ruta, el controlador y el app.js del backend. Desde ya muchas gracias

Migracion de User.js:

```
 'use strict';



 /** @type {import('sequelize-cli').Migration} */


module.exports = {


    async up(queryInterface, Sequelize) 
{
    await queryInterface.createTable('User',
{id: 
    {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },

  name: {
    type: Sequelize.STRING,
    allowNull:false
  },

  lastname:{
    allowNull:false,
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  },

  password: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.TEXT
  },

 roles_id: {
    allowNull: false,
    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
  }
});


},



async down(queryInterface, Sequelize) {
await queryInterface.dropTable('Users');
  }
};
```

Modelo User.js:

```
module.exports = (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
    let alias = 'User'
    let cols = {
        id: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        name: {
            type: dataTypes.TEXT(20),
            allowNull: false
        },
        lastname: {
            type: dataTypes.TEXT(100),
            allowNull: false
        },
        password: {
            type: dataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull:null
        },
        roles_id: {
            type: dataTypes.INTEGER
        }
    }
    let config = {
        tableName: "users",
        timestamps: false,  
    }
    const User = sequelize.define(alias, cols, config);
   User.associate = (models)=>{
        User.belongsTo(models.Rol, {
            as : 'rol',
            foreignKey : 'roles_id'
        })
    }
    return User;
  };
```

controlador mainController.js (no le den bola al validador ni al token, no los estoy usando aun):

```
const bcrypt= require("bcrypt");
const { validationResult } = require("express-validator");
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const User= require("../../database/models/User");


const controller = {
 
 home: async (req, res) =>{
     
     try{
      return res.json({message:"mama"});

    }catch(error){
      res.send({ error });
    }
    },

    processRegister: async (req, res) => {
      const errors = validationResult(req);

      if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.render("RegisterUsuario.jsx", { errors: errors.mapped(), oldData: req.body });

      }const newUser = {
        name: req.body.nombre,
        lastname: req.body.apellido,
        password: bcrypt.hashSync(req.body.password,10),
        roles_id: req.body.roles,
      }

      try {
        if (User) {
          await User.create(newUser);

        } else {
          console.log('El modelo User no está definido correctamente.');
        }

        const token= jwt.sign({id: newUser.id},"SECRET",{
          expiresIn: 86400
        })

        console.log(token)
        res.redirect("/");
  
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
      };
}};

 
 module.exports= controller;
```

la ruta de main.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mainController = require('../../controllers/api/mainController')




router.get("/",mainController.home);
router.get("/home", mainController.home);
router.post("/Registro-usuario", mainController.processRegister);



module.exports = router;
```

el archivo app.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const expressSession= require("express-session")
const path= require("path")
const methodOverride= require("method-override")
const cookieParser= require("cookie-parser")
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const morgan = require("morgan")


const app = express();
const cors = require("cors");
var corsOptions = {
    origin: "*"
  };



app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(expressSession({secret:"SECRET"}));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(methodOverride('_method'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(morgan("dev"))





const mainRoutes = require("./src/routes/api/main");

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/build')));
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, "./public")));
console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, "./public"));




app.use("/api", mainRoutes);


const port = process.env.PORT || 3001;
app.listen(port, () => console.log('Server escuchando en puerto http://localhost:3001'));
```

el archivo App.js de React en el frontend:

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home"
import Header from "./components/Header";
import RegisterUsuario from "./components/RegisterUsuario";


function App() {

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api/home")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));

  fetch("/api/Registro-usuario")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => console.log(data))
    .catch((error) => console.error(error));
}, []);

   return(
        
     <div className="App">
  
      <BrowserRouter>
        
        <Routes className="navbar">
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} className="lista"/>
          <Route path="/api/Registro-usuario" element={<RegisterUsuario />} className="lista" />
        </Routes>
        <Header />
    </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

El error es este:

TypeError: User.create is not a function
at processRegister (C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\Sistema de turnos\backend\src\controllers\api\mainController.js:37:22)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\Sistema de turnos\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\Sistema de turnos\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\Sistema de turnos\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\Sistema de turnos\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\Sistema de turnos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\Sistema de turnos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
at next (C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\Sistema de turnos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
at Function.handle (C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\Sistema de turnos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
at router (C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\Sistema de turnos\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)